# Python doctring repeating param description

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

I am developing a python module and I have a problem because I copy and paste documentation.

It is a simple one but I have multiple functions where the parameter definitions inside the docstring are the same. See the example below.

```python
def method1(common_param: str, param_coffee):
    """
    This method make coffee.

    :param  common_param:  The same parameter description
    :param  param_coffee:  Specific coffee parameter
    """
    ...

def method2(common_param: str, param_tea):
    """
    This method make tea.

    :param  common_param:  The same parameter description
    :param     param_tea:  Specific tea parameter
    """
    ...
```

I mostly write the documentation because it is displayed on PyCharm when you hover the function with your mouse. Unfortunately this IDE doesn't go look for the right explanation when I link the parameter description.

*PyCharm screenshot where the parameter definition isn't correct*
[image]

Will it be possible to link them instead of copy and paste the parameter description ?
Does it have a convention to avoid repeating parameter description in Python ?
Maybe with something like `:see @method1.param.common_param:`

Comment: did you try it with another string?

Comment: @GhostOps What do you mean by another string?

Comment: like replace the ```:see @input_.param.history_id:``` instead of something and check whether its only for that kind of string or not, but anyway, mostly no one would link docstrings to another param's docstring, better just copy-paste it. Thats better and very simple though